# Is there any built-in control in ASP.NET other than `dropdownlist` to display time?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to display time starting from 8AM To 7PM With interval 15 minutes. So:

- 8.15AM
- 8.30AM
- 8.45AM
- 9AM
- 9.15AM
- 9.30AM

In a dropdownlist. Is there any built-in control in ASP.NET other than `dropdownlist` to display time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find something at [eworldui](http://www.eworldui.net/CustomControls/TimePickerDemo.aspx) or [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/DateAndTimePicker.aspx)
Doing a search for "asp.net time picker" will reveal some others, too.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing native to display time, you'll need to do it in a drop down list. From a usability perspective, I'd be inclined to break it into one list for hour and another for the 15 minute interval. Depending on your design, you may have the values for the lists stored in a database so can just bind the tables to the lists or alternatively just implement a loop within the code behind and add the list items programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

To fill your dropdownlist, you could try something like:

```
Dim dt As DateTime = #8:00:00 AM#

For i As Integer = 0 To 44
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(dt.ToString("hh:mmtt"))
    dt = DateAdd(DateInterval.Minute, 15, dt)
Next
```

Comment: Thank u very much.Now the time is displaying as,for eg:08:00AM.Instead of that i need to display 8:00AM.What change i have to make in ur given code?

Comment: To not include the leading "0", change the ToString formatting to: "h:mmtt"